# Can't import .sage file in same directory

Tags: sage

I have Sage files called "a.sage" and "b.sage" in the same directory, and a.sage includes the line "from b import blah". However, when I run "sage a.sage" from the command line, I get "ImportError: No module named b".

I've tried preparsing b.sage and I've tried adding '.' to the end of SAGE_PATH in my .bashrc file. Can't find any more suggestions. I would appreciate someone's help with this, because I'm pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `.sage` files aren't Python modules.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.sage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from b import foo
ImportError: No module named b
```

If you want to import a module in this way, I think you will need to make a *Python* module.

```
$ mv b.sage b.py
$ sage a.sage
hi
```

However, you'll need to import things from Sage as need be in the Python file, e.g. `from sage.all import ZZ`.

Extra very useful info from @Dima Pasechnik:

You can do this alternately by doing `sage b.sage` which generates a Python file `b.sage.py` which you need to copy to `b.py` (or even better, create a symlink, i.e. `ln -s b.sage.py b.py` - you'd only need to do this once). Now `import b` will work.

Comment: Not really the answer I wanted to hear (ugh, starting to regret my choice of Sage), but thank you! It might just be easier to merge them into one file. I'll investigate both options. Thanks again.

Comment: instead of working with b.py, you can still work with b.sage, without extra imports etc. You need to "compile" your b.sage, by running "sage b.sage".
This will produce "b.sage.py", which you need to copy to "b.py" (or even better, create a symlink, i.e. "ln -s b.sage.py b.py" - you'd only need to do this once). Now "import b" will work.

Comment: Ah, that was the extra step!  I'll update my answer.